# How to test multiple websocket connections with logged in users?

Tags: node.js, react-native, testing, websocket

I'm working on a polling tool and want a bunch of users to connect to my **nodejs server** from a **React Native app** via **websockets**. To be able to poll the user needs to login first. It is already working, when I log in with one user and do the poll.

I want to **test** it as there were multiple users at the same time using the app and doing the poll, so that I can see the poll results changing in real time.

How can I build those test requests to a webserver via websockets from let's say 20 different virtual clients? My main problem is that I have no idea how to simulate those 20 different virtual clients connecting to a websocket and to let them fake-react to push messages coming from the server. Which tools/frameworks would be good to use here also maybe with automatic session/cookie management for the login?

Answer (score 0):

You could go with any of the following:

- Setup **end-to-end tests** with a tool like [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org) (search online for: "react native selenium" and you should see even more tool candidates for that job) that allows you to instantiate multiple browser clients and run actions (your tests) on the client.
- A simpler way would be to create a custom script with **node.js** to connect as a **client** to the server. From there you could:

  - Either Simulate multiple web socket connections via javascript code **EASIER**
  - Or create an additional BASH script which along with a tool like [screen](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-screen-on-an-ubuntu-cloud-server) should run your node.js client multiple times on the same terminal window.